# Git post recieve hook with ssh key with google cloud platform with bitnami

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have local clone repo of private GitHub repo.I want to push master branch to production server via post-receive hook.

But I am unable to do so, I guess ssh access is messed up. I have google compute engine instance with bitnami/Debian 9.

How do I set ssh key and test the ssh key?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, first you can check out if the firewall-rule is already create on the project:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list | grep 22
```

Therefore if is not there, create it:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-ssh --allow tcp:22
```

Then to create a SSH key from your workstation you can follow the [Google Doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) is pretty clear explained how to do it.

On my case I add my public SSH key to my VM from Google Console > VM instances > click on the instance > Edit > from "SSH keys" you can drop your SSH key. And save.

Also I found this [info](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/connect-ssh/) I think it fits on your case.

Hope it could be useful